# Why do Microsofts AKS samples separate manifests for deployment and service?

Tags: kubernetes, azure-devops, azure-aks

As discussed in this question, it's best practice to register the services before the actual deployment:
[Why should I specify service before deployment in a single Kubernetes configuration file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50409392/why-should-i-specify-service-before-deployment-in-a-single-kubernetes-configurat)

However in [these official Microsoft examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/kubernetes-manifest?view=azure-devops#deploy-action) there is a deployment task, that has the order the other way around.

```
    - task: KubernetesManifest@0
      displayName: Deploy
      inputs:
        action: deploy
        manifests: manifests/deployment.yml|manifests/service.yml
```

Does it not matter for AKS if service or deployment are executed first?

The [official guidelines for docker](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/manage-deployment/#organizing-resource-configurations) it's stated that this is relevant..

Does Microsoft AKS handle it differently/better than plain k8s?
Are the services automatically registered first, since they can be recognized as such?
Else why split it in 2 files if one could not guarantee the order of execution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is a misunderstanding of the input in `manifests` parameter. `manifests/deployment.yml|manifests/service.yml` means `manifests/deployment.yml` **or** `manifests/service.yml`. The sample is trying to say you can input `manifests/deployment.yml` **or** `manifests/service.yml`, there is no order here. In addition, if you run the pipeline, you'll find format `manifests/deployment.yml|manifests/service.yml` is not supported.

Comment: This statement confuses me now quite a bit. When I chose the "deploy to AKS" template for the azure pipeline, I'm pretty sure it generated a deployment.yml and a service.yml and also references both in the same KubernetesManifest Task.

Comment: Could you double confirm the format is `manifests: |
                $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/manifests/deployment.yml
                $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/manifests/service.yml` or `manifests: manifests/deployment.yml|manifests/service.yml`?

Comment: it generates it in this form: 
manifests: |                 $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/manifests/deployment.yml                 $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/manifests/service.yml
which would be using both files.
only in that documentation the two files are OR-ed

Comment: The documentation `manifests/deployment.yml|manifests/service.yml` is a sample, this format is not supported. `manifests: |                 $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/manifests/deployment.yml                 $(System.ArtifactsDirectory)/manifests/service.yml` is a correct format.

Comment: yes. this is the correct format. 
but does this format make sure the service is registered before the deployment is executed? 
That was my question.
Maybe it doesn't matter because AKS always uses some form of DNS?

Comment: I don't think DevOps register service before the deployment is executed. The process should be defined in the manifest files.